# laravel session route redirection error on multiple input fields

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following controller whenever i hit submit it redirects me to sales. Where as it should return admin.invoice.index page rather than sale.index. can any one please help?

```
  $data = array();
    for ($i=0; $i < count($request['product_id']); ++$i) 
    {
     $sales= new Sale;        
     $sales->product_id = $request['product_id'][$i];
     $sales->qty= $request['qty'][$i];
     $sales->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
     $sales->save(); 
     $product = new Product;
     $product->where('id', '=', $request['product_id'][$i])->decrement('stock', $request['qty'][$i]);
     $data[]['sales'] = $sales;
     $data[]['product'] = $product;

 }

 $data = [];
 if ($request->session()->has('data')) {
    $data = $request->session()->get('data');


}
Session::flash('success', 'Sale is successfully');
return view('admin.invoice.index')->with('data', $data);
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the `data` with `with()` through `session`.

```
{
    $data = array();
    for ($i=0; $i < count($request['product_id']); ++$i) 
    {
     $sales= new Sale;        
     $sales->product_id = $request['product_id'][$i];
     $sales->qty= $request['qty'][$i];
     $sales->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
     $sales->save(); 
     $p = new Product;
     $p->where('id', '=', $request['product_id'][$i])->decrement('stock', $request['qty'][$i]);
     $product = Product::where('id', '=', $request['product_id'][$i])->first();
     $data[$i]['sales'] = $sales;
     $data[$i]['product'] = $product;
   }

   Session::flash('success', 'Sale is successfully');
   return redirect('/invoice')->with('data', $data);
}
```

Then, Make a new route -

```
Route::get('/invoice', function(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request){
      $data = [];
      if ($request->session()->has('data')) {
            $data = $request->session()->get('data');
      }

      return view('admin.invoice.index')->with('data', $data);
});
```

Comment: Undefined variable: product
besides that it's still redirecting me back to sales.index
Any help to solve this problem.

Comment: may be you are missing something else, show us the full controller and your route definition, you may add your view also

Comment: what is your url definition of `admin.invoice.index` and it is not redirecting, it is showing page on post route that's why you are seeing as old route

Comment: I don't have any url setup for admin.invoice.index

Comment: can you please tell me what will be the best way to send this post route data to admin.invoice.index?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164489/discussion-between-muhammad-shahzad-and-sohel0415).

Comment: Undefined variable: request:
in route
if ($request->session()->has('data'))

Comment: Undefined index: sales
Undefined index: products

Comment: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given {{dump($data)}} 

{{dd($data}} shows json fields.

Comment: try `{!! dump($data) !!}`

Comment: ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Array to string conversion

Comment: try `dd($data)` before `return view('admin.invoice.index')->with('data', $data);` line

Comment: array:2 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "sales" => Sale {#231 ▶}
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "product" => Product {#228 ▶}
  ]
]

Comment: @MuhammadShahzad I have edited my answer again, use it, it will be fine now

Comment: i'm getting the ans in this format.
{"product_id":"1","qty":"1","user_id":1,"updated_at":"2018-02-04 11:15:15","created_at":"2018-02-04 11:15:15","id":90} []
any quick way to get in proper form?

Comment: you are getting answer in the form of an object, just access it like object using `->` and in my sense it its a nice format. If you really want to use it like array, then use `toArray()` on collection to get it as array but i would suggest you to keep it that way

Comment: How can I access products? I can access sales qty,
i have product name, selling price, in my index i have accessed it like, {{ $sale->product->name }}

Comment: inside foreach you could do `$d['product']->name`

Comment: {{$d['product']->name}} returns nothing.
{{$d['product']->selling_price}} returns nothing.

Comment: what does `{!! dump($d['product'])!!}` gives you, just play with your data, this is very basics of php, you have data, just play with it, you will have a way for sure

Comment: {!! dump($d['product'])!!} It displays all the fields in the json format. however i cannot access it's content  {{$d['product']->name}} with this format. Can you please help?

Comment: i have updated my answer, use it, it should work fine

Comment: {!! dump($d['product'])!!} results this,  
Product {#212 ▼
  #fillable: array:6 [▼
    0 => "name"
    1 => "purchased_price"
    2 => "selling_price"
    3 => "stock"
    4 => "user_id"
    5 => "category_id"

Comment: Call to a member function first() on integer

Comment: $product = Product::where('id', '=', $request['product_id'][$i])->decrement('stock', $request['qty'][$i])->first();
it is a separate model and table, when the sales is created, the product stock get's decremented.

Comment: BTW i don't think you need product in your session array as you can easily get the product with relationship.

Comment: Thank you so much. You are my saviour :).
I didn't quite get it.
BTW i don't think you need product in your session array as you can easily get the product with relationship

Comment: that's different issue, forget it for now, enjoy the time as you have made your code work :)

Comment: Thanks Sohel0415, it's only because of you. I owe you a great deal. Stay blessed dear.

Answer (score 1):

@Sohel0415
My Sales Controller is like this.

```
public function index()
        {
            $sales = Sale::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
            return view('admin.sales.index', compact('sales'));
        }


        public function create()
        {

            $products = Product::pluck('name', 'id', 'qty')->toArray();
            return view('admin.sales.create', compact('products'));
        }

        public function store(Request $request)
        {

           $data = array();
           for ($i=0; $i < count($request['product_id']); ++$i) 
           {
               $sales= new Sale;        
               $sales->product_id = $request['product_id'][$i];
               $sales->qty= $request['qty'][$i];
               $sales->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
               $sales->save(); 
               $product = new Product;
               $product->where('id', '=', $request['product_id'][$i])->decrement('stock', $request['qty'][$i]);
               $data[]['sales'] = $sales;
               $data[]['product'] = $product;

           }
           Session::flash('success', 'Sale is successfully');
           return view('admin.invoice.index')->with('data', $data);

    }

admin.invoice.index

@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
@foreach($data as $d)
    {{$d['sales']}} 
    {{$d['product']}} 
@endforeach
@endsection

My web.php or routes:

    Route::resource('categories', 'CategoriesController');
        Route::resource('products', 'ProductsController');
        Route::resource('sales', 'SalesController');
```

Comment: Please do update your question rather adding another comment in answers section.